# How can I match an element after certain string, but not include it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Javascript and I'm wondering how can I use regex to match an element after certain word, and before another sign.

For instance, return *1*  from this string

```
localhost:8080/user/1/somethingelse/
```

I've tried

```
/user\/([0-9]*)+\/g
```

but it returns

```
user/1/
```

Any help would be hightly appreciated.

Comment: What's your search criteria ? Just match between two slashes ?

Comment: You are probably requesting group 0 instead of group 1.

Comment: `/user\/([0-9]+)/.exec(s)[1]` or `s.match(/user\/([0-9]+)/)[1]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the second one fits perfect!! Cheers buddy!